# Given a histogram as a list, how can I find Otsu's method?

Tags: python, image-processing

so I'm doing a task where a histogram is returned to me as a list. And from that list, I am supposed to find Otsu's method.

How would I go about it, just stuck and lost as any reference I've seen so far directly takes an image as the input and conducts otsu's method on it directly.

Comment: Google search shows different code sources for Otsu method such as [this](https://github.com/bornreddy/smart-thresholds/blob/master/otsu.py)

Comment: You don’t find Otsu’s method. You *use* Otsu’s method to find a threshold value. Even Wikipedia explains the method using a histogram and shows code that uses a histogram. Are you sure you searched?